# How to Change Default Path of saveas Dialog using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JavaScript I am firing an `execCommand (SaveAs)` to open a windows save as dialog box.

The data I am saving is inside iframe and I am giving the code the file name to use.  This all works fine.

What I need to do is make the dialog box point to a specific folder path when rendered to the user.

I have researched out on the web several ways but have found none using JavaScript.

Here is the function I am calling in JavaScript :

```
fnSaveCOTContents = function(COTFileData, COTFileName, COTFilePath) {
    hiddenCOTiFrame.document.open("text/html","replace");
    hiddenCOTiFrame.document.write(COTFileData);
    hiddenCOTiFrame.document.close();
    hiddenCOTiFrame.focus();
    hiddenCOTiFrame.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, COTFileName);
}
```

`COTFilePath` contains `c:\foldername\`